# firebase CRUD issue when chaining server?

Tags: jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got a static site, which I would like to use firebase as database.

However I've never really worked with Firebase etc. So I have been looking at various CRUD samples, hoping I'll be able to modify em to fit my site..

The problem is that I have found this sample/tutorial:
[Tutorial and Download sample](http://time2hack.com/2015/03/intro-to-firebase-with-javascript-and-jquery.html)

It works fine out of the box, but when I change the database URL it looks to break the script.

Nothing happens when I add a new content?

Am I missing something to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Your using older version of firebase, try to use new version of firebase i.e 4.3.1

[Firebase Documentation for latest version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) Go through this link, it will really helpful for you. I hope. Please feel free to ask any doubts regarding and this [See this firebase for SQL developers, it will be more useful for CRUD Operations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacqhiI-g_o&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)